# Не работает скрипт при подключении другого скрипта

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Проблема в следующем. 
Есть страница со скриптом:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="general.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.warning {
color: red;
      }
</style>
<script>
$(function()
{
var maxLength = $('#textarea').attr('maxlength');  
$('#textarea').keyup(function()
{
    var curLength = $('#textarea').val().length;
    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, maxLength)); 
    var remaning = maxLength - curLength;
    if (remaning < 0) remaning = 0;
    $('#textareaFeedback').html(remaning + ' осталось символов');
    if (remaning < 10) // когда менять цвет
    {
        $('#textareaFeedback').addClass('warning')
    }
    else
    {
        $('#textareaFeedback').removeClass('warning')
    }
 })
 })
 </script>
 </head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea" maxlength="25"></textarea>
<div id="textareaFeedback"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Если к странице подключить

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="general.js"></script>
```

То скрипт, который на странице, перестаёт работать.

Код файла general.js:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.notification .close').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().fadeOut();
});

});
```

Как можно решить проблему? Чтобы было подключено два скрипта, и один и второй работал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в строчке `jQuery.noConflict()` в general.js. При использовании этой функции jQuery не объявляет функцию `$`, вместо неё объявляется функция `jQuery`. Так что либо не используйте опцию `noConflict` (и замените `jQuery` на `$` в general.js), либо в теле html вместо `$` используйте `jQuery`.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь всё ОК.